# NSLocalizedString only retrieves the key, not the value in Localizable.strings (IOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, uialertview, nslocalizedstring, localizable.strings

I've made a strings file named "Localizable.strings" and added two languages to it, like so:

```
"CONNECTIONERROR" = "Check that you have a working internet connection.";
"CONNECTIONERRORTITLE" = "Network error";
```

I have also converted the files to Unicode UTF-8
However, when I create a UIAlertView like this:

```
 UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
 initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CONNECTIONERRORITLE",nil)
 message:NSLocalizedString(@"CONNECTIONERROR",nil)                    
 delegate:self
 cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
 otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

the alert view only shows the key text, not the value. It works if I, for example, set a UITextviews text to NSLocalizedString(@"CONNECTIONERROR",nil), but the alert view only displays the key. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: `NSLocalizedString()` returns the key if it fails to find the key/value pair.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't copy/paste the code so it was a type-o. The code in my  app however, is correct.

Comment: Found the problem. It doesn't work for me in the iPhone simulator so I tested it on an actual device and it worked.

Comment: Check out this [answer][1], it may help.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8972349

Comment: Don't be afraid to use underscores or spaces in the key.

Comment: I am also facing this issue. checked the all the files in Project Navigator. Localizable.strings file is added twice. so I removed one file, and Localize that file for Base(English), and other one Spanish.

Comment: I still not able to make it work. UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"WARNING", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"LOGIN_NRIC_REQUIRED", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil]; is not working got LOGIN_NRIC_REQUIRED. Any idea?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tested the app on an actual device and it worked

Comment: Another problem is that the Localizable.strings file doesn't get cleaned out and re-initialized properly; if you were testing on the device before and then created or significantly altered your Localizable.strings files the changes aren't always noticed, so you have to CLEAN your build AND delete the copy from the device before the changes propagate properly.

Comment: Uninstalling the app from the simulator worked for me.

Comment: I find that deleting the app from the Build Products folder on the Mac is enough make Xcode use all the latest files.

Answer (score 113):

In my case it was because I had mistakenly named the file "Localization.strings" and hadn't noticed (it has to be named Localizable.strings).  As explained previously the symptom is because the compiler cannot find the string. Otherwise the cause could be any number of things but usually it's a missing semi colon or quotation mark. These are hard to find when you're doing a lot of localizations at once. The lesson learned is to start building your localization file early on in your development process and build it as you go, so that they are easier to spot.

Comment: note that the filename is case sensitivity. So you have to use ".strings" instead of ".Strings"

Comment: The file should be name _Localizable.string_, with a upper *L*, without a *s*...
Convention over configuration... I **hate** this paradigm.

Comment: Localizable.strings in my case as well. Spent good two hours trying to find what was causing the problem.

Answer (score 27):

Same problem, solved using the filename: Localizable.strings

Answer (score 20):

Double check that the `Localizable.strings` file is being added to

> Targets -> BuildPhases -> Copy Bundle Resources

It hadn't been added automatically for me.

**Edit 2021:** with XCode 12 the `Localizable.strings` have to be added to

> Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile resources

Answer (score 19):

Change your `.strings` file name to `Localizable.strings`, it worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

I have been searching the solution for 5 hours, I tried everything I could to make my app localization working.

The problem was that one of the Pods of my project had a Localizable.strings file (actually it was Parse pod that had not renamed it). Therefore my Localizable.strings file was not recognized by my app.

I fixed the issue by changing the name of the file to "MyappnameLocalizable.strings" and using NSLocalizedString this way:

```
        NSLocalizedString("key", tableName: "MyappnameLocalizable", comment: "comment")
```

Answer (score 9):

I was having problems with this on the iOS Simulator. I ended up deleting the Localization.strings file in the simulator directory

> ( /Users/(me)/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/5.0/Applications/(etc)/(project)/(application.app)

cd to there and delete all copies of Localization.strings found there.

For some reason the usual rubber chicken voodoo of build clean, quit iOS Simulator, quit XCode, etc wasn't working, but this did.  At least for me, today.

Answer (score 8):

This is happening when the runtime can't find the specified key, for whatever reason. In your case, it's most likely due to a typo: `CONNECTIONERRORITLE` is missing a `T` for `TITLE`. Also pay attention to any warnings/error when compiling regarding the `Localizable.strings` file: if there are unbalanced `"` or missing `;` the file cannot be compiled/read correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Change the name of the file to Localizable.strings, make sure the target in the file inspector is set. 
To avoid syntax errors right click on Localizable.strings file->open as->ASCII property list
Also, cleaning the project and building again helped in my case.

Comment: This is also a great way to find errors in Localizable.strings file.

Answer (score 6):

NSLocalizedString usage means you need the EXACT case and spelling of your key in order to get the content from it.  You'll notice that this one says

```
NSLocalizedString(@"CONNECTIONERRORITLE",nil)
```

when it should be

```
NSLocalizedString(@"CONNECTIONERRORTITLE",nil)
```

If you look at the last part of the first one, it says 'ITLE', not 'TITLE'

Comment: We recently changed the names of enums to start with lowercase during a transition to newer Swift.  But we forgot that we derive some long string keys from the enum names. The names no longer matched.  The one different character was well into the middle so it was hard to notice.  I was checking the string match by using Xcode's 'find' feature.  Since that was case-insensitive, it found the keys and I assumed they matched.  Your answer here made me double-check and find the error. Thanks.  (Now our default value will change so we notice immediately in debug builds.)

Answer (score 6):

If you wrote double semicolons at the end of a line, NSLocalization does not working.
You should check Localizable.strings file if there is ';;'

Comment: yes , it is happened to me i check and resolve this ... thank you for help .

Answer (score 6):

Rename the InfoPlist.strings file to Localizable.strings (double clic) and then you will get the correct string for that key.

Answer (score 6):

When you are developing an SDK. You need some extra operation.

1) create **Localizable.strings** as usual in YourLocalizeDemoSDK.

2) create the same **Localizable.strings** in YourLocalizeDemo.

3) find your **Bundle Path** of YourLocalizeDemoSDK.

**Swift4**:

```
// if you use NSLocalizeString in NSObject, you can use it like this
let value = NSLocalizedString("key", tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), value: "", comment: "")
```

`Bundle(for: type(of: self))` helps you to find the bundle in YourLocalizeDemoSDK. If you use `Bundle.main` instead, you will get a wrong value(in fact it will be the same string with the key).

But if you want to use the String extension mentioned by [dr OX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29384360/4789773). You need to do some more. The origin extension looks like this.

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.main, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

As we know, we are developing an SDK, `Bundle.main` will get the bundle of YourLocalizeDemo's bundle. That's not what we want. We need the bundle in YourLocalizeDemoSDK. This is a trick to find it quickly.

Run the code below in a NSObject instance in YourLocalizeDemoSDK. And you will get the URL of YourLocalizeDemoSDK.

```
let bundleURLOfSDK = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).bundleURL
let mainBundleURL = Bundle.main.bundleURL
```

Print both of the two url, you will find that we can build bundleURLofSDK base on mainBundleURL. In this case, it will be:

```
let bundle = Bundle(url: Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Frameworks").appendingPathComponent("YourLocalizeDemoSDK.framework")) ?? Bundle.main
```

And the String extension will be:

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        let bundle = Bundle(url: Bundle.main.bundleURL.appendingPathComponent("Frameworks").appendingPathComponent("YourLocalizeDemoSDK.framework")) ?? Bundle.main
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

To find out if the Localizable.strings file is being found, check the content of your .app build and you can also do this in code:

//en is for English for example so specify yours here
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];

If path is NULL, it means file not found.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any extra semicolon in your strings file, it doesnt localise.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem, suddenly my localizable strings didn't work at all. Then I used file-compare with the old .strings copy, and at-last I found I have accidentally deleted a key in it.

So Definitely if the format is wrong Xcode will not read the strings for you.

This is the format it expects **"Key" = "Value";**

Answer (score 2):

Because I stumbled upon this when looking for the answer to a similar problem, I'm leaving my solution here:

If your key has "\u2028" in it instead of "\n", it will always return just the key and not the value. Seems to be a bug with localization.

Comment: It appears to me that neither \u2028 nor \n work with localization.  I gave you a +1 anyway for acknowledging the defects in localization which has not really been stable since xCode 9.2.

Answer (score 2):

We were dealing with an issue in which some keys were not getting their values despite all of them existing in Localizable.strings.

Turns out that the developer who built the file added two semi-colons at one line, and that caused the parsing of this file to be quite erratic.

After I found the two semi-colons one next to the other and got rid of one of them, the app wouldn't compile anymore. At this point I was able to find some lines that didn't have semi-colons. After fixing those and the app compiled, all my strings worked fine.

So having two semi-colons in the same line caused the file to compile despite it missing semi-colons in other lines.

It looks like Apple's parser for `.strings` file is very primitive.

Unfortunately, the plist linter was useless in our case. To find and fix the issue, I copied and pasted the entire contents of our Localizable.strings file (which is over 2000 lines long), and started copying it back in 20 line chunks and compiling each time. It was the only way to find an issue that the linter would not catch.

Comment: I had a single backquote at the end of a line after a semicolon - one of these:  `  , basically just looks like a fleck of dust on the screen. In terms of finding it - also possible to use binary search - first, I put a string definition for a string used in the main screen at line one of the file, then at the halfway point, then continue to split the remaining distance in half depending on whether the string comes out correctly or just as the key.

Answer (score 1):

Put an ; at end of the lines in the Localizable.strings files.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting the simulator settings worked for me.

iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings...

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I tried clean project and delete derived data still not work. I remove several line breaks in the strings file and then Xcode find the strings again.

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggested solutions worked for me, but I did solve the issue by deleting the .app file in Products

Answer (score 1):

I had the issue when one language was working properly and other language worked half of the time and other time I was getting the key, instead of localized version of that key.

Problem in my case was that after manually merging version control conflict, there was extra line of '>>>>>' left, project didn't complain (not like when you miss the semicolon, it complains) and was building properly, so every key before that '>>>>>' was being translated and every key after, not.

If more simpler solutions fails, you might have to go through every line and look for extra characters (not only '>>>>>', other extra characters too), or if you are using the version control get older, stable version of Localizable.strings file and manually go through changes and add later commits.

Comment: Thanks. In my case it was one Plus char "+" before one of the keys in the Localizable.string file that was added by me while the merging process accidentally

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the localization file must contain a mapping, otherwise the SDK won't read the file.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to not put '@' in front of your `key` or `value` like so:

```
@"key" = @"value";
```

It should be just:

```
"key" = "value";
```

The '@' only goes in front of the key when accessing it:

```
NSWebLocalizedString(@"key", @"label for coder");
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?

Answer (score 0):

I had everything working when suddenly localization just stopped translating strings. This means the file is somehow unreadable to Xcode.

This had happened to me because I had pasted a bad character in the `Localized.strings` file. When I deleted the few lines with the offending character (a non unicode character? bad quote signs? Couldn't tell) everything went back to normal.

To find the offending lines I made a breakpoint, and manually translated the strings in my file in the debugger, until I hit the first one that won't translate.

Answer (score 0):

For xcode 9.2 removing "Localizable.strings" files from the simulators for the project using console solved it for me. Here is the commands for the lazy ones like me ;)

Do not forget to replace **YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE** with your project name

Shell script:

```
cd
cd Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/
find . -name "Localizable.strings" | grep "YOUR_APP_NAME_HERE.app" | xargs rm
```

If you are experiencing the problem with Unit Tests it will work in simulator ;)

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4:

If you use more than one bundle such as you use it in an external framework:

```
var currentBundle = Bundle.main
NSLocalizedString("CONNECTIONERRORITLE", tableName: nil, bundle: currentBundle, value: "", comment: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using this approach.

The `localize` file was created with the name `main.Strings`. Then, I open the `main.Strings` files (for each language added) and I renamed them manually with the name `localize.strings` and add them one by one to my project, also I deleted the `main.strings`.

The second thing to evaluate is: check . your file, all the `keys` have to end with `;` and be sure all the `quotes` are properly opened and closed.

And you can use in **swift 4** :

```
myButon.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("forgotpassword.key", comment: ""), for: UIControlState.normal)
```