# String resources Xcode + swift

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift

I am new in iOS developing and in Swift language.
And I try to make simple iOS application, and I need to have some string resources (for labels and text fields) in app. Of course, I can put this strings to my *.swift files as constants, but I think, it is a bad way. How can I do it? I need something as string resources in Android. I use Xcode 6 beta with swift.

TY for answers ;)

Comment: Did you have a look at the [Resource Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/Introduction/Introduction.html) ? There is a section about "String Resources".

Comment: Yes, it's nice, thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your best bet is creating a file called `Localizable.strings`. In this file you can make localised string variables you can use throughout your application.
Define strings like this;

```
"hello_world" = "Hello World!";
```

Use them in your Obj/C code like so;

```
NSLocalizedString(@"hello_world", nil);
```

Or in Swift;

```
NSLocalizedString("hello_world", comment: "")
```

**p.s., I haven't tested this. Swift code might be faulty because of the fact I can't test this atm.**

Comment: See (for example) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081757/whats-nslocalizedstring-equivalent-in-swift for the Swift translation.

Comment: Can I have more than 1 Localizable file? I'm trying to create a Text based game and I want to separate the text from the logic, would this be a viable solution?

Comment: How I can use this in IB?