# XLFormDescriptor initialize with Title in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xlform

Why this works OK:

```
let formFescriptor = XLFormDescriptor(title: "Sign Up");
```

And this:

```
let formFescriptor = XLFormDescriptor(title: NSLocalizedString("Sign Up", comment: nil));
```

Gives me error:

```
Cannot invoke initializer for type 'XLFormDescriptor' with an argument list of type '(title: String)'
```

**Why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NSLocalizedString have non-optional comment, while you are passing nil into it. Change comment to something meaningful in a context, so NSLocalizedString will be initialized properly, as well as XLFormDescriptor.

Comment: Indeed! I didn't know about `= default` before)) `NSLocalizedString("Sign Up", comment: "")` works as well.

Answer (score 3):

Ib Objective-C `NSLocalizedString`is a macros defined in `NSBundle.h`:

```
#define NSLocalizedString(key, comment) \
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] localizedStringForKey:(key) value:@"" table:nil]
```

In Swift it's a function:

```
func NSLocalizedString(key: String, tableName: String? = default, bundle: NSBundle = default, value: String = default, #comment: String) -> String
```

You can use it as:

```
let title = NSLocalizedString("Sign Up", tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
let formDescriptor = XLFormDescriptor(title: title)
```

Or you can use equivalent code called from the macros:

```
let title = NSBundle.mainBundle().localizedStringForKey("Sign Up", value: nil, table: nil)
let formDescriptor = XLFormDescriptor(title: title)
```

Another nice idea is to add a nice method to `String` class to have nice syntax. Here is an example from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29384360/434224):

```
extension String {
    var localized: String {
        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
let formDescriptor = XLFormDescriptor(title: "Sign Up".localized)
```