# swift NSLocalizedString string get value error

Tags: string, swift, nslocalizedstring

Hello I have app with 2 language strings file

en.strings
tr.strings

and my strings file codes here

en.strings

```
language = "English";
```

tr.strings

```
language = "Turkish";
```

I want to show in my link which language using current user example;

```
  let commingLanguage: String =  String(format: NSLocalizedString("language", comment: ""))


  print(commingLanguage)  // giving output nothing
```

i want to use commingLanguage string English or Turkish value ?
How can i do that my codes dont showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the syntax should be:

```
"language" = "English";
```

Comment: Then maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081757/whats-nslocalizedstring-equivalent-in-swift