# How do I translate my hard-coded strings in swift 2.0?

Tags: localization, internationalization, swift2

Despite all the info available on the web, I am still struggling to translate my hard-coded strings in Swift (target language: French) - How do I go about translating, for example, the title **Week A** in the following code:

```
let titleButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 32))
    titleButton.setTitle("Week A", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    titleButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "CollegiateHeavyOutline", size: 25.0)
```

or the placeholder text in the following code:

```
timeTextField.placeholder = "Type in start time"
```

A step by step answer will be much much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081757/whats-nslocalizedstring-equivalent-in-swift

Comment: Does not seem to work for me... Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the hard coded text would change to another language this is called localization.
so you have to implement localization in your project.
follow this [link](http://rshankar.com/internationalization-and-localization-of-apps-in-xcode-6-and-swift/).

Comment: How would you write it in code for my Week A title (in my question); can't seem to be making it work after looking at the link...

Comment: you have to add 2 string file in your code 1 for english and 1 for french. you have to some configuration in your project after that you just put the key with localised syntax  and the compiler get the string value from your string file .

Comment: follow the tutorial for this at first you have to do some work.

Comment: I am giving it another shot ;). I have got the 2 strings files already.

Answer (score 0):

I made it - yes! I did the following:

```
let titleButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 32))
    titleButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("WEEK_A", comment: "Name of the week A"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    titleButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "CollegiateHeavyOutline", size: 25.0)
```

and for placeholder text:

```
timeTextField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("TYPE_IN_START_TIME", comment: "start time")
```

Following the link in the accepted answer was really helpful!