# Export for localization error

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode8

When I'm trying to export my files for translation I'm getting this log:

> [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-12169/IDEFoundation/Localization/IDELocalizationWork.m:355
>   Details:  Failed to read strings file "/var/folders/ny/054nwfjs63v3v9rlpkfbt94w0000gn/T/Xcode3SourceStringsAdaptor-EAAAA7F1-000C-432D-BB22-49394ECF78A9/Localizable.strings", underlying error:
>   The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
>   Object:   
>   Method:   -work
>   Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}
>   Please file a bug at http://bugreport.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.

I have checked this file, it doesn't belong to my files and it is empty. Why Xcode is trying go localize this file instead of my project Localizable.strings? Xcode is creating new, empty file in new temp folder every time I try to export.

I'm using `String` extension that is adding `localized` computed var like in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081757/whats-nslocalizedstring-equivalent-in-swift)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that export tool scans for `NSLocalizedString` calls in code of Your app. With `String` extension it is not able to parse source files successfully.

After replacing all `"text_id".localized` calls with `NSLocalizedString("text_id", comment: "")`, export works fine.

Hope it will help someone.