# NSLocalizedString runtime error on Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I'm developing an app with Swift and SpriteKit. I've converted my code from Swift 2.3 to Swift 3, but when I run the code I get the following error:

> Thread 1:EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP.subcode=0x0)

The error show up on this line. I've created `okLabel` with `SKLabelNode`.

```
okLabel.fontName = (text: NSLocalizedString("dialogOKFont", comment: "")) as! String
```

On `Localizable.strings(Base)`, I've defined `"dialogOKFont"` as follows:

```
"dialogOKFont" = "Optima-Bold";
```

I really appreciate if someone gives me an answer or hint to fix this error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're casting to a string outside of the parenthetical s for your font.  Also, check out this extension http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25081757/whats-nslocalizedstring-equivalent-in-swift

Comment: ! means "please crash if what i'm looking for isn't there".

Comment: Paulo Mattos' answer explains the problem. But do you really want to use NSLocalizedString to get a font name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
okLabel.fontName = NSLocalizedString("dialogOKFont", comment: "")
```

Your original code had two related mistakes:

- you wrapped the localized string in single element tuple: `(text: ...)`
- and then you casted this tuple back to `String`, resulting in the `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` crash

Using *only* `NSLocalizedString(...)` is enough to get the localized `String` you were after :)