# Why NSLocalizedString returns key, but not value, if used in app, which has framework target?

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

Our application had a serious issue in production. The problem was that, for some languages, users did not see the localized strings, but actual keys! I did not think that this was possible, because it should have selected the English language as default if a person had applied some localization settings. Please, let me know what I am doing wrong:

1. I have created a custom Strings file (not Localizable.strings, but with a specific name: `Test.strings`). Those strings are translated into 4 languages.
2. I add those `Test.strings` to our **framework target**.
3. Our framework has extension localized, which looks like this:

​

```
func localized() ->String {

        let frameworkBundle = Bundle(identifier: "com.framework")!
        var localizedString = NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: "Test", bundle: frameworkBundle, value: "", comment: "")
        return localizedString
}
```

It should work perfectly. Why it is not a case? Perhaps I should do something in the application target? Maybe the issue comes from the fact, that application target does not has any `Localizable.string`s for that language?

Comment: In the example code you are looking for an empty string as value "". The same problem happens when you specify a value?

Comment: Problem seems like your app is not able to find the strings file, maybe you can double check that this is the right identifier for the Bundle, and also that the strings file is in the right target.

Comment: You are finding the bundle incorrectly. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182437/341994

Comment: @matt  thanks! Can I keep Tests.string instead of Localizable.strings?

Comment: @vauxhall how can I specify the value, if it is generic string?