# NSLocalizedString returning keys instead of values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8, nslocalizedstring

I'm working on a app. In that some of NSlocalizedString returning keys instead of values. I have tried all the possibilities like,

1. Quit the xcode,
2. Cleaned the derived data,
3. Cleaned the product,
4. Deleted the app from simulator,
5. Also tried running it in the device.

Still it's not working. can any one help me how to solve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: show your tried code always

Comment: Try the possibility that your keys are not present in your Localizable.strings file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NSLocalizedString only retrieves the key, not the value in Localizable.strings (IOS)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251177/nslocalizedstring-only-retrieves-the-key-not-the-value-in-localizable-strings)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I already checked,The keys are there in the  Localizable.strings file. @ Josh Caswell