# Localizable.strings doesn't work at all anymore

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, nslocalizedstring

I was adding the localization feature on a branch named 'Localization'. However, I had to submit a hot fix, so I changed branches, did the fix and returned back to the 'Localization' branch. Now `NSLocalizableStrings()` doesn't work at all anymore, for any language; it only displays the keys.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251177/nslocalizedstring-only-retrieves-the-key-not-the-value-in-localizable-strings) question and have tried all of the suggestions listed there but none has worked for me.

- I've made sure the file name is correct
- I've used `plutil -lint` to ensure the `Localizable.strings` files are valid
- I've `Reset Content and Settings` of the simulator
- I've tried cleaning the project and reinstalling the app on the simulator
- I've tried running on an actual device (same issue appears on the device)
- I've tried restarting Xcode
- I've tried restarting my machine

Not a single one of these things worked. Does anyone have any ideas? It was all working fine a few minutes ago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps that worked for me:

1. Uninstall the application from Simulator.
2. Clean the project.
3. Make some sort of change to each of the `Localizable.strings` files in the project (this is to invalidate some kind of cache, I suppose). Just an extra space worked for me.
4. Run the application.

Comment: just 2 did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

1. Add your Localised file or Strings
2. Make sure your language code is correct
3. Uninstall your App in simulator or device
4. Clean build folder (cmd+shift+k)
5. Now run the Application

Now working...

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

1. You said you did checked names, but you wrote "localisable.string", should be "Localizable.strings"
2. Clean (Shift+cmd+k)
3. Switch from .string file to .xib or storyboard and back
4. See if the modified strings still there
5. Check for missing ; in the storyboard strings (as it doesn't raise errors at compile time)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `Localizable.strings` in the question. I followed those steps, still no luck